# R Group datetime efficiently in intervals for large datasets

Tags: r, datetime, time, intervals, group-by

I have dozens of daily datasets with a column representing `datetime`. Each dataset, `df` is relatively large (+50k). I need to count how many `datetime` registries I have for every 3 minute intervals.

Sample of data:

```
time
21/05/2010 19:59:37
21/05/2010 08:40:30
21/05/2010 09:21:00
21/05/2010 22:29:50
21/05/2010 11:27:34
21/05/2010 18:25:14
```

Steps: 
Putting values in datetime format: `df1$time <- as.POSIXct(df1$time, format ="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")`

Getting 3 minute intervals: `df1$min3 <- cut(df1$time, breaks = "3 min", )`

Counting events per interval: `df2 <- aggregate(df1, by = list(df1$min3) , length )`

The problem is, each file has different first registry times. E.g. Some start at 5:35 am, other at 5:33, so the first would have 5:35-5:38-5:41 intervals whereas the second would have 5:33-5:36, etc.

I need to set a common start for all the datasets when I do my intervals. But I am stack with it (particularly because I don't even know what "programming term" I should be looking for). Any one has any idea how to set the breaks starting at the same time for every df? (please bear in mind I have many days)

Data:

```
    df1 <- structure(list(arrtime = c("21/05/2010 19:59:37", "21/05/2010 08:40:30", 
"21/05/2010 09:21:00", "21/05/2010 22:29:50", "21/05/2010 11:27:34", 
"21/05/2010 18:25:14", "21/05/2010 15:16:01", "21/05/2010 09:41:53", 
"21/05/2010 15:01:29", "21/05/2010 09:02:06")), .Names = "arrtime", row.names = c(448L, 
496L, 622L, 712L, 740L, 785L, 907L, 912L, 984L, 1078L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I guess you could check the `min` value from all these datasets and select the `min` datetime as the first entry for the `cut`.

Comment: I think I will padd the datasets, all of them, automatically, from a very early time (e.g. 1 hour before usual registries). I will do all the calculations like this, and then cut off the excess. So, I would like to put on hold this question, maybe I can get it on my own.

Comment: @user3507584: The code to get the 3 mins interval does not work `df1$min3 <- cut(df1$time, breaks = "3 min", )`